# How to create a single file archive of a huge directory of around 18 gb

Tags: linux, command-line, centos

I have a directory containing around 1800 files in a directory , the directory size is now around 18gb. I need to create a single archive of the directory in order to download the whole contents. I have created a tar archive and downloaded the file , tried two times  every time when I extract the archive file it says

> The file is corrupted

so how can I create an archive of the whole 18gb directory with recovery record / verification such that it wont get corrupted. I don't need any compression on the archive. The 18gb directory exists on a Linux remote server with command line access only (minimal os)

Note: there is also some issues , cant split and combine the files because there are 1800 files. Also its difficult to download small small ranges of files from the 1800 files. The download is to local Windows machine from Linux remote machine over HTTP.

Comment: How are you downloading it?  If you're using FTP, be sure you're in `binary` mode.

Comment: downloading by HTTP

Comment: You might want to look at rsync

Comment: @ogetWidgetCount i want to download the files to my local windows machine over HTTP

Comment: Why is there the desire to download over http?  Any reason why we shouldn't suggest other methods?

Comment: @nerdwaller cant download 18gb all at once since using download managers need to pause and resume fun

Comment: Are you limited to clicking in your browser to download or is a script a possibility?  I don't understand why you can't `split` your tar file into chunks, say, 50 of them, not 1800, then `cat` them together once you've downloaded them all.  Can you run a `sum` utility on both ends to compare checksums?

Comment: @NicoleHamilton it contains win executable so if i split and combine that exec should work , i tried once , it was a failure since combining the files is done by "cat"  command the execs dont work as it gets damaged

Comment: Then your best bet is to break it up, do 18 1g tarballs. or as @NicoleHamilton said, the split method with checksums on both ends.

Comment: If you `split -b` a file, then `cat` the chunks back together in the correct order and don't get **exactly** what you started with, you have either a bad `split` or a bad `cat` or bad both.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton anyway how can i archive to a single file the 18gb directory , why should i split if there is a way to archive the directory

Comment: I don't think we understand your problem or the constraints.  The reason for splitting is the obvious suspicion that the problem is the size of what you're transferring.  Can you transfer smaller files and checksum they're correct?  You may not like it, but this may be what you have to do.

Comment: @cc4re 1. Learn to format your posts. 2. DON'T IN ALL CAPS. It's rude.

Answer (score 3):

It might be an issue with the file system on the Windows side.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) says

> The maximum possible size for a file on a FAT32 volume is 4 GB minus 1 byte

This does not apply if you are using NTFS.

So if you are using FAT32 make sure that you combine your original list of files into 5 archives a bit smaller than 4GB each.

Comment: am using NTFS file system no issues